# Colorschemes not working in gvim despite working in Vim in the terminal

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I'm having the following issue: 256-color colorschemes are not working in Gvim, but they work fine in Vim on the terminal.

This issue is happening on both my Ubuntu machine and on my Mac OSX machine. From what I've read this issue is the opposite of what most people encounter: usually GVim can deal with any colorscheme and people instead have colorscheme issues running Vim on terminals.

I have the following .vimrc (I have a .gvimrc with nothing in it):

```
" For Pathogen
execute pathogen#infect()

colorscheme 256-grayvim 

set shiftwidth=3
set tabstop=3
set expandtab

set ruler
set nu

syntax on
set nowrap
```

When I open Vim in a terminal 256-grayvim works perfectly. When I open up Gvim, 256-grayvim shows as loaded (typing `:colorscheme` returns 256-grayvim) however the colors are completely wrong - they are the default white background and black text. Furthermore, if I then type `:colorscheme 256-grayvim`, or select the colorscheme through GVim's Edit menu there is no change in colorscheme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

256-grayvim does not define gui colors it only defines terminal colors.

You can see this when you look in 256-grayvim.vim

```
hi Normal       ctermfg=253         ctermbg=235        cterm=None
```

`cterm*` arguments to highlight only affect terminal colors. To set the gui colors you need the `gui*` arguments instead.

So changing these might work.

```
ctermfg -> guifg  
ctermbg -> guibg
cterm   -> gui
```

But you will probably need to find the equivalent color for gui colors because they don't accept 256 colors

---

Edit: Heres a function that will try and convert all cterm things to their gui equivalent. (It will also replace None to NONE since MacVim was complaining it didn't like None). The first 64 lines are defining a lookup table that matches the 256 color with its color in hex.

```
function! Convert_256()
let ct = {
    \   '00'  : '000000',    '01'  : '800000',    '02'  : '008000',    '03'  : '808000',
    \   '04'  : '000080',    '05'  : '800080',    '06'  : '008080',    '07'  : 'c0c0c0',
    \   '08'  : '808080',    '09'  : 'ff0000',    '10'  : '00ff00',    '11'  : 'ffff00',
    \   '12'  : '0000ff',    '13'  : 'ff00ff',    '14'  : '00ffff',    '15'  : 'ffffff',
    \   '16'  : '000000',    '17'  : '00005f',    '18'  : '000087',    '19'  : '0000af',
    \   '20'  : '0000d7',    '21'  : '0000ff',    '22'  : '005f00',    '23'  : '005f5f',
    \   '24'  : '005f87',    '25'  : '005faf',    '26'  : '005fd7',    '27'  : '005fff',
    \   '28'  : '008700',    '29'  : '00875f',    '30'  : '008787',    '31'  : '0087af',
    \   '32'  : '0087d7',    '33'  : '0087ff',    '34'  : '00af00',    '35'  : '00af5f',
    \   '36'  : '00af87',    '37'  : '00afaf',    '38'  : '00afd7',    '39'  : '00afff',
    \   '40'  : '00d700',    '41'  : '00d75f',    '42'  : '00d787',    '43'  : '00d7af',
    \   '44'  : '00d7d7',    '45'  : '00d7ff',    '46'  : '00ff00',    '47'  : '00ff5f',
    \   '48'  : '00ff87',    '49'  : '00ffaf',    '50'  : '00ffd7',    '51'  : '00ffff',
    \   '52'  : '5f0000',    '53'  : '5f005f',    '54'  : '5f0087',    '55'  : '5f00af',
    \   '56'  : '5f00d7',    '57'  : '5f00ff',    '58'  : '5f5f00',    '59'  : '5f5f5f',
    \   '60'  : '5f5f87',    '61'  : '5f5faf',    '62'  : '5f5fd7',    '63'  : '5f5fff',
    \   '64'  : '5f8700',    '65'  : '5f875f',    '66'  : '5f8787',    '67'  : '5f87af',
    \   '68'  : '5f87d7',    '69'  : '5f87ff',    '70'  : '5faf00',    '71'  : '5faf5f',
    \   '72'  : '5faf87',    '73'  : '5fafaf',    '74'  : '5fafd7',    '75'  : '5fafff',
    \   '76'  : '5fd700',    '77'  : '5fd75f',    '78'  : '5fd787',    '79'  : '5fd7af',
    \   '80'  : '5fd7d7',    '81'  : '5fd7ff',    '82'  : '5fff00',    '83'  : '5fff5f',
    \   '84'  : '5fff87',    '85'  : '5fffaf',    '86'  : '5fffd7',    '87'  : '5fffff',
    \   '88'  : '870000',    '89'  : '87005f',    '90'  : '870087',    '91'  : '8700af',
    \   '92'  : '8700d7',    '93'  : '8700ff',    '94'  : '875f00',    '95'  : '875f5f',
    \   '96'  : '875f87',    '97'  : '875faf',    '98'  : '875fd7',    '99'  : '875fff',
    \   '100' : '878700',    '101' : '87875f',    '102' : '878787',    '103' : '8787af',
    \   '104' : '8787d7',    '105' : '8787ff',    '106' : '87af00',    '107' : '87af5f',
    \   '108' : '87af87',    '109' : '87afaf',    '110' : '87afd7',    '111' : '87afff',
    \   '112' : '87d700',    '113' : '87d75f',    '114' : '87d787',    '115' : '87d7af',
    \   '116' : '87d7d7',    '117' : '87d7ff',    '118' : '87ff00',    '119' : '87ff5f',
    \   '120' : '87ff87',    '121' : '87ffaf',    '122' : '87ffd7',    '123' : '87ffff',
    \   '124' : 'af0000',    '125' : 'af005f',    '126' : 'af0087',    '127' : 'af00af',
    \   '128' : 'af00d7',    '129' : 'af00ff',    '130' : 'af5f00',    '131' : 'af5f5f',
    \   '132' : 'af5f87',    '133' : 'af5faf',    '134' : 'af5fd7',    '135' : 'af5fff',
    \   '136' : 'af8700',    '137' : 'af875f',    '138' : 'af8787',    '139' : 'af87af',
    \   '140' : 'af87d7',    '141' : 'af87ff',    '142' : 'afaf00',    '143' : 'afaf5f',
    \   '144' : 'afaf87',    '145' : 'afafaf',    '146' : 'afafd7',    '147' : 'afafff',
    \   '148' : 'afd700',    '149' : 'afd75f',    '150' : 'afd787',    '151' : 'afd7af',
    \   '152' : 'afd7d7',    '153' : 'afd7ff',    '154' : 'afff00',    '155' : 'afff5f',
    \   '156' : 'afff87',    '157' : 'afffaf',    '158' : 'afffd7',    '159' : 'afffff',
    \   '160' : 'd70000',    '161' : 'd7005f',    '162' : 'd70087',    '163' : 'd700af',
    \   '164' : 'd700d7',    '165' : 'd700ff',    '166' : 'd75f00',    '167' : 'd75f5f',
    \   '168' : 'd75f87',    '169' : 'd75faf',    '170' : 'd75fd7',    '171' : 'd75fff',
    \   '172' : 'd78700',    '173' : 'd7875f',    '174' : 'd78787',    '175' : 'd787af',
    \   '176' : 'd787d7',    '177' : 'd787ff',    '178' : 'd7af00',    '179' : 'd7af5f',
    \   '180' : 'd7af87',    '181' : 'd7afaf',    '182' : 'd7afd7',    '183' : 'd7afff',
    \   '184' : 'd7d700',    '185' : 'd7d75f',    '186' : 'd7d787',    '187' : 'd7d7af',
    \   '188' : 'd7d7d7',    '189' : 'd7d7ff',    '190' : 'd7ff00',    '191' : 'd7ff5f',
    \   '192' : 'd7ff87',    '193' : 'd7ffaf',    '194' : 'd7ffd7',    '195' : 'd7ffff',
    \   '196' : 'ff0000',    '197' : 'ff005f',    '198' : 'ff0087',    '199' : 'ff00af',
    \   '200' : 'ff00d7',    '201' : 'ff00ff',    '202' : 'ff5f00',    '203' : 'ff5f5f',
    \   '204' : 'ff5f87',    '205' : 'ff5faf',    '206' : 'ff5fd7',    '207' : 'ff5fff',
    \   '208' : 'ff8700',    '209' : 'ff875f',    '210' : 'ff8787',    '211' : 'ff87af',
    \   '212' : 'ff87d7',    '213' : 'ff87ff',    '214' : 'ffaf00',    '215' : 'ffaf5f',
    \   '216' : 'ffaf87',    '217' : 'ffafaf',    '218' : 'ffafd7',    '219' : 'ffafff',
    \   '220' : 'ffd700',    '221' : 'ffd75f',    '222' : 'ffd787',    '223' : 'ffd7af',
    \   '224' : 'ffd7d7',    '225' : 'ffd7ff',    '226' : 'ffff00',    '227' : 'ffff5f',
    \   '228' : 'ffff87',    '229' : 'ffffaf',    '230' : 'ffffd7',    '231' : 'ffffff',
    \   '232' : '080808',    '233' : '121212',    '234' : '1c1c1c',    '235' : '262626',
    \   '236' : '303030',    '237' : '3a3a3a',    '238' : '444444',    '239' : '4e4e4e',
    \   '240' : '585858',    '241' : '626262',    '242' : '6c6c6c',    '243' : '767676',
    \   '244' : '808080',    '245' : '8a8a8a',    '246' : '949494',    '247' : '9e9e9e',
    \   '248' : 'a8a8a8',    '249' : 'b2b2b2',    '250' : 'bcbcbc',    '251' : 'c6c6c6',
    \   '252' : 'd0d0d0',    '253' : 'dadada',    '254' : 'e4e4e4',    '255' : 'eeeeee',
    \}

%s/cterm\(\w\+\)=\([A-Za-z]\+\)/\=submatch(0) . ' gui' . submatch(1) . '=' . submatch(2)/g
%s/cterm\(\w\+\)=\(\d\+\)/\=submatch(0) . ' gui' . submatch(1) . '=#' . ct[submatch(2)]/g
%s/cterm=\(\w\+\)/\=submatch(0) . ' gui' . '=' . submatch(1)/g
%s/None/NONE/g
endfunction
```

When it is run on 256-grayvim it produces this.

```
" Vim color file
" Maintainer:   Piotr Husiatyński <phusiatynski@gmail.com>

set background=dark
set t_Co=256
let g:colors_name="256-grayvim"

let python_highlight_all = 1
let c_gnu = 1


hi Normal       ctermfg=253 guifg=#dadada         ctermbg=235 guibg=#262626        cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi Cursor       ctermfg=Red guifg=Red         ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi SpecialKey   ctermfg=87 guifg=#5fffff          ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi Directory    ctermfg=76 guifg=#5fd700          ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi ErrorMsg     ctermfg=124 guifg=#af0000         ctermbg=White guibg=White      cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi PreProc      ctermfg=246 guifg=#949494         ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi Search       ctermfg=160 guifg=#d70000         ctermbg=232 guibg=#080808        cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi Type         ctermfg=75 guifg=#5fafff          ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi Statement    ctermfg=75 guifg=#5fafff          ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi Comment      ctermfg=244 guifg=#808080         ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi Identifier   ctermfg=111 guifg=#87afff         ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi DiffText     ctermfg=88 guifg=#870000          ctermbg=250 guibg=#bcbcbc        cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi Constant     ctermfg=208 guifg=#ff8700         ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi Todo         ctermfg=233 guifg=#121212         ctermbg=118 guibg=#87ff00        cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi Error        ctermfg=233 guifg=#121212         ctermbg=124 guibg=#af0000        cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi Special      ctermfg=160 guifg=#d70000         ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi Ignore       ctermfg=220 guifg=#ffd700         ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi Underline    ctermfg=244 guifg=#808080         ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=NONE gui=NONE

hi FoldColumn   ctermfg=247 guifg=#9e9e9e         ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi StatusLineNC ctermfg=247 guifg=#9e9e9e         ctermbg=234 guibg=#1c1c1c        cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi StatusLine   ctermfg=247 guifg=#9e9e9e         ctermbg=233 guibg=#121212        cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi VertSplit    ctermfg=247 guifg=#9e9e9e         ctermbg=234 guibg=#1c1c1c        cterm=Bold gui=Bold

hi LineNr       ctermfg=238 guifg=#444444         ctermbg=244 guibg=#808080        cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi LineNr       ctermfg=247 guifg=#9e9e9e         ctermbg=235 guibg=#262626        cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi NonText      ctermfg=87 guifg=#5fffff          ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE       cterm=Bold gui=Bold


hi Pmenu        ctermfg=White guifg=White       ctermbg=DarkGray guibg=DarkGray    cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi PmenuSel     ctermfg=NONE guifg=NONE        ctermbg=Gray guibg=Gray        cterm=Bold gui=Bold
hi PmenuSbar    ctermfg=DarkGray guifg=DarkGray    ctermbg=DarkGray guibg=DarkGray    cterm=NONE gui=NONE
hi PmenuThumb   ctermfg=Gray guifg=Gray        ctermbg=Gray guibg=Gray        cterm=NONE gui=NONE

"vim: sw=4
```

If you replace your 256-grayvim with the above it should work in both gvim and the terminal. (I have no idea how it looks though)